# WN server filter won't work

Tags: python

WN servers have an alternative to cgi programs called filters.  I have been trying to get one to work, but I have had no luck.  I am writing in python.  It looks like the server is not receiving any output from the program but is parsing nothing and wrapping this nothing in my standard header and footer.  I have chmod 755 the program and my index.wn file reads:

```
Default-Attributes=parse

 Default-Wrappers=templates/template1.inc


 File=includeTests.html

 File=index.html

 File=archives.html

 File=contact.html


 File=style.css


 File=testProgram.py


 #here is the stuff about the filter

 File=testFilter.html

 Content-type=text/html 

 Filter=testProgram.py

 Attributes=parse, cgi
```

here is what is in the filter called testProgram.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"

print "hi"
```

testProgram.py works perfectly if it is shoved into a cgi-bin folder and chmoded.  I suppose my problem may lay with the fact that I have never ever seen a filter program in python.  I'm not sure I have even seen a filter program at all.  Does anyone out there have any experience with wn servers and filters?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have no real-world WN experience, but I've read its [docs](http://hopf.math.northwestern.edu/docs/filter.html) and it seems to me there's something wrong with your code -- quoting,

> no headers should be supplied by the
>   program as WN will automatically
>   provide them. For example, while a
>   CGI/1.1 program typically starts with
>   printing "Content-type: text/html"
>   followed by a blank line, this should
>   not be done for "someprogram" in the
>   index.wn entry above, because WN will
>   automatically provide the appropriate
>   HTTP/1.1 headers based on the
>   "Content-type=text/html" line in the
>   index.wn file.

while you do seem to be supplying a header in your code.  Second, you sure you want [parsing](http://hopf.math.northwestern.edu/docs/parse.html), as you're requesting?

I don't see why either of these issues should just "swallow" your program's output, though, so this is hardly a complete answer... but maybe it could be a start.

BTW, since you say

> I'm not sure I have even seen a filter
>   program at all

the one example of filter I see in the docs is `zcat` -- at least this does make clear that a filter is a program that takes the given file as its standard input (but doesn't *have* to read it, the docs say... but that file, even if ignored as in your example code, **must** exist -- could that perhaps be the problem...?) and gives the contents (not headers) to send back on its standard output.